# Is it correct to say "he went back to where he was" or "he went back where he was"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

If we say "**he went back to where he was**", then "**where he was**" is like a noun such as a house/ a place.

If we say "**he went back where he was**", then "**where he was**" is like an adverb or a prepositional phrase such as "**to his house**" or "**to his place**".

Are "**he went back to where he was**" and "**he went back where he was**" interchangable?

But I guess people would say "**put your toy back where it belongs**" because there is one example from the dictionary saying "[**He put the note where she could easily see it.**](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/where)"

The toy could be "**on a table**", "**in a box**" or "**at the door**", and we have to pick the preposition if we use "**where it belongs**" as a noun.  For example,

-"**put your toy back in where it belongs**"

-"**put your toy back at where it belongs**"

-"**put your toy back on where it belongs**"

But these sound weird, but "**he went back to where he was**" doesn't sound weird.

Why do we say "**to where...**" or "**from where...**" but not "**in/at/on where...**"?

Comment: **To** and **from** suggest directions. The others indicate locations.

Comment: In "He went back to France"the word "to" indicates a location. In "It came from China" the word "from indicates a location.